# Set owner of file produces security ID error

Tags: java, windows, user-permissions, file-ownership

I am attempting to allow users to attach files to my form, in Java, and have these files saved into a specific directory in a storage drive. Because our system places a limit on the amount of space a user can have in the storage, we created a user whose sole purpose is to be the owner of these files.

However, I am receiving this error: "This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object."

This error comes up in my console, as well as if I try to make this user the owner manually through Properties>Security>Advanced.

What must I do to this user to allow them to be set as the owner and avoid this error?

Comment: In Java?  No idea.  In C, you would need to enable restore privilege, which overrides the usual security rules.  (Incidentally, it sounds as if directory quotas might be more sensible than user quotas in your environment.  They often are.)

Comment: Either in Java or in the security settings themselves, I don't particularly care as long as it works :)

Comment: There is no way to configure Windows so that it always allows you to assign arbitrary owners, as that would be in conflict with the Windows security model.  (Unfortunate, IMO, but there you are.)  The only way to do it is for the software to turn on restore privilege.  Perhaps there's an existing question about how to do that in Java?  Or one of the Java experts may be able to help.